# Python Pandas: Complex Subset from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with Groups, two dates, and a value.

I want a subset of the dataframe which keeps all rows with a unique B_DATE value for each GRP.  Where there are duplicate B_DATE values within each group, I want to keep the rows with the maximum A_DATE value.

So, if my initial dataframe were:

```
GRP  A_DATE        B_DATE   VALUE
A   12/31/2012  2/19/2014   546.2
A   12/31/2013  2/19/2014   543.7
A   3/31/2013   4/30/2014   473.3
A   3/31/2014   4/30/2014   472.5
A   6/30/2013   7/30/2014   528.7
A   6/30/2014   7/30/2014   531.5
A   9/30/2013   10/30/2014  529
A   9/30/2014   10/30/2014  546.7
A   12/31/2014  2/18/2015   573.5
A   3/31/2015   4/30/2015   458.7
A   6/30/2015   7/30/2015   519.5
B   3/31/2014   7/7/2015    1329
B   12/31/2014  7/7/2015    1683
B   3/31/2015   7/7/2015    1361
B   6/30/2014   8/13/2015   1452
B   6/30/2015   8/13/2015   1429
B   9/30/2014   10/29/2015  1488
B   9/30/2015   10/29/2015  1595
B   12/31/2015  2/16/2016   1763
B   3/31/2016   4/28/2016   1548
```

I would want the result to look like this:

```
GRP  A_DATE        B_DATE   VALUE
A   12/31/2013  2/19/2014   543.7
A   3/31/2014   4/30/2014   472.5
A   6/30/2014   7/30/2014   531.5
A   9/30/2014   10/30/2014  546.7
A   12/31/2014  2/18/2015   573.5
A   3/31/2015   4/30/2015   458.7
A   6/30/2015   7/30/2015   519.5
B   3/31/2015   7/7/2015    1361
B   6/30/2015   8/13/2015   1429
B   9/30/2015   10/29/2015  1595
B   12/31/2015  2/16/2016   1763
B   3/31/2016   4/28/2016   1548
```

I know how to do this through cumbersome looping and using argmax().  However, wondering if there is a 'clean', efficient, Pythonic way to approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use 'groupby' with 'max'?

Comment: @SuperStew - !!1 ah - do you mean like groupby(DATE_B).max()?

Comment: yea somthing like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values(['GRP','A_DATE'], ascending=[True,False])\
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['GRP','B_DATE'])
```

Output:

```
   GRP      A_DATE      B_DATE   VALUE
7    A   9/30/2014  10/30/2014   546.7
10   A   6/30/2015   7/30/2015   519.5
5    A   6/30/2014   7/30/2014   531.5
9    A   3/31/2015   4/30/2015   458.7
3    A   3/31/2014   4/30/2014   472.5
8    A  12/31/2014   2/18/2015   573.5
1    A  12/31/2013   2/19/2014   543.7
17   B   9/30/2015  10/29/2015  1595.0
15   B   6/30/2015   8/13/2015  1429.0
19   B   3/31/2016   4/28/2016  1548.0
13   B   3/31/2015    7/7/2015  1361.0
18   B  12/31/2015   2/16/2016  1763.0
```

And, add `sort_index` to get back original order:

```
df.sort_values(['GRP','A_DATE'], ascending=[True,False])\
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['GRP','B_DATE']).sort_index()

   GRP      A_DATE      B_DATE   VALUE
1    A  12/31/2013   2/19/2014   543.7
3    A   3/31/2014   4/30/2014   472.5
5    A   6/30/2014   7/30/2014   531.5
7    A   9/30/2014  10/30/2014   546.7
8    A  12/31/2014   2/18/2015   573.5
9    A   3/31/2015   4/30/2015   458.7
10   A   6/30/2015   7/30/2015   519.5
13   B   3/31/2015    7/7/2015  1361.0
15   B   6/30/2015   8/13/2015  1429.0
17   B   9/30/2015  10/29/2015  1595.0
18   B  12/31/2015   2/16/2016  1763.0
19   B   3/31/2016   4/28/2016  1548.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to groupby `B_DATE` and 'GRP' aggregate the last value i.e

```
df['A_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A_DATE'])
df['B_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B_DATE'])

ndf = df.groupby(['GRP',df['B_DATE']]).agg('last').reset_index()
```

```
     GRP     B_DATE     A_DATE   VALUE
0    A 2014-02-19 2013-12-31   543.7
1    A 2014-04-30 2014-03-31   472.5
2    A 2014-07-30 2014-06-30   531.5
3    A 2014-10-30 2014-09-30   546.7
4    A 2015-02-18 2014-12-31   573.5
5    A 2015-04-30 2015-03-31   458.7
6    A 2015-07-30 2015-06-30   519.5
7    B 2015-07-07 2015-03-31  1361.0
8    B 2015-08-13 2015-06-30  1429.0
9    B 2015-10-29 2015-09-30  1595.0
10   B 2016-02-16 2015-12-31  1763.0
11   B 2016-04-28 2016-03-31  1548.0
```